# Double click event for Kendo Treeview control items for MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-treeview

1.What I have is a Kendo TreeView control similar to the below structure.

```
-  Parent 1
      - Child 1 of Parent 1
      - Child 2 of Parent 1
- Parent 2
```

2. I need to trigger an event on Double click of any of the items listed above in the treeview.
3. There exists an event for single click, that is .Select(). But I don't seem to find one for double click.

Is there any way to trigger a double click event from the control itself, if not, what is the suggested alternate for the same?

Any help/suggestions appreciated

Thanks in advance

PS: I'm using Kendo Trial Version for my POC and want to check whether I'll be able to implement the desired funtionalities for my project before it commenences.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: thanks :) it is working